# npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org with meteor-up

Tags: linux, docker, dns, debian, iptables

My colleague uses meteor-up to deploy docker containers on a debian machine. We recently had a server reboot which deleted some iptables we added to avoid the ufw + docker security flaw.

I'd like to have a fresh configuration for the security flaw (since it was a bit messy at first) so I added the following to iptables as stated in the docker documentation :

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
```

My colleague is getting the following error when deploying :

```
#14 [7/6] RUN cd /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm

    #14 41.92 npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN

    #14 41.92 npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN

    #14 41.94 npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

    #14 41.95

    #14 41.95 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

    #14 41.95 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-07T09_25_12_763Z-debug.log

    #14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

I don't know if this error is docker based or iptables based. I suspect a dns problem so I tried the following :

```
sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It seems no dns server is reachable when using the default (bridge) docker network. However if I use the host network :

```
sudo docker run --network host busybox nslookup google.com
Server:         213.186.33.99
Address:        213.186.33.99:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.185.78

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

Do I need to change iptables ? Or is it a networking problem ? or both ?

EDIT 1

It's definitely an iptables problem. I tried to do the same commands on a server that did not have those iptables and it worked. The moment I added the iptables, it stopped working.

Comment: EDIT 1 : run some tests on iptables configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to allow ESTABLISHED traffic on the public interfaces with iptables.